# Error 'tags and values not the same' when using tf.metrics.auc

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to log the AUC for a segmentation task to tensorboard but am having some trouble that I can't get around. I know that the code runs to completion when the AUC-relevant lines are not included. It seems as if one of the two variables being passed to tf.metrics.auc has no shape associated with it whatsoever.

My training code is defined thusly:

```
def run_model():

    valCosts=[]
    GLOBAL_STEP = 0
    minLoss=10000000000
    pred = uNet3D_noBN(X, BETA[j], KERNEL_SIZE)
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(Y,[-1]),logits=tf.reshape(pred,[-1])))
    auc  = tf.metrics.auc(tf.reshape(Y,[-1]),tf.reshape(tf.nn.sigmoid(pred), [-1] ), num_thresholds=50)

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    # this with statement updates the BN parameters if BN is being used
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR[i]).minimize(cost)

    with tf.name_scope("training"):
        tf.summary.scalar("training_cost", cost, collections=['training'])
        tf.summary.scalar("training_auc", auc, collections=['training'])
        for var in tf.trainable_variables():
            tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name , var, collections=['training'])

    with tf.name_scope("validation"):
        tf.summary.scalar("validation_cost", cost, collections=['validation'])
        tf.summary.scalar("validation_auc", auc, collections=['validation'])


    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        train_merge      = tf.summary.merge_all(key='training')
        validation_merge = tf.summary.merge_all(key='validation')
        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter( graphDir + '/training/', sess.graph)
        validation_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter( graphDir + '/testing/', sess.graph)
        print('Beginning Session!')
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        print('Running Model!')

        while GLOBAL_STEP <= int(np.floor(MAX_ITER/BATCH_SIZE[k])):

            if GLOBAL_STEP % NUM_STEPS != 0:
                x,y=draw_batch(train_dir,BATCH_SIZE[k])
                y[y>0]=1
                flip = random.uniform(0,1)
                if flip>0.5:
                    x = np.flip(x,2)
                    y = np.flip(y,2)
                _, acc, c = sess.run([optimizer, train_merge, cost], feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
                _
                train_writer.add_summary(acc, GLOBAL_STEP)
                #train_writer.add_summary(summary, GLOBAL_STEP)
            else:
                x,y=draw_batch(val_dir,BATCH_SIZE[k])
                y[y>0]=1
                acc, c = sess.run([validation_merge,cost], feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
                validation_writer.add_summary(acc, GLOBAL_STEP)
                #validation_writer.add_summary(summary, GLOBAL_STEP)
                #save_path=saver.save(sess, outDir + '/model')
                print(c)
                if c < minLoss:
                    save_path=saver.save(sess, outDir + '/model')
                    minLoss=c                        
                valCosts.append(c)



            GLOBAL_STEP+=1
        g= open(graphDir+'/val.pickle', 'w+')   
        pickle.dump([valCosts], g)


for k in range(0,len(BATCH_SIZE)):
    for i in range(0, len(BETA)):
        for j in range(0, len(LR)):
            X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE[k], None, None, None, 1],   name='X')  #input
            Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [BATCH_SIZE[k], None, None, None, 1], name='Y')  #'labels'
            hypers = dict(zip(('LR','EPS','BETA', 'BATCH_SIZE', 'NUM_STEPS', 'KERNEL_SIZE', 'NUM_CHANNELS'), (LR[i], EPS, BETA[j], BATCH_SIZE[k], NUM_STEPS, KERNEL_SIZE, NUM_CHANNELS)))

            os.chdir(launch)
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        outDir  = '/home/mira/karl_data/striatum/outputs/' + timestr
        os.mkdir(outDir)

        graphDir = outDir
        os.mkdir(graphDir + '/training/')
        os.mkdir(graphDir + '/testing/')


        with open(outDir + '/hyperparams.txt', 'w+') as f: 
            for key, value in hypers.items():
                f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))



        run_model()
        tf.reset_default_graph()
```

And when I run this I get the following errors:

File "grid_search.py", line 78, in run_model
    tf.summary.scalar("validation_auc", auc, collections=['validation'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py", line 90, in scalar
    val = _gen_logging_ops.scalar_summary(tags=tag, values=tensor, name=scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 623, in scalar_summary
    "ScalarSummary", tags=tags, values=values, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in **init**
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): tags and values not the same shape: [] != [2] (tag 'validation/validation_auc')
     [[Node: validation/validation_auc = ScalarSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](validation/validation_auc/tags, validation/validation_auc/values/_39)]]

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139085/invalidargumenterror-when-using-summary-in-tensorflow-v1-2-1?rq=1